# counting new lines, new tabs and spaces in C using getchar()

Tags: c

I created a table that count new line, new words, sapces and tabs.
I successfully count all of them but the problem is on the output:

I am trying to print one line only with the result with what I am am counting but instead the output is the whole count (the increment).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    int c,nl,nw,nc,state;
    int newspace, tabchar;
    state = OUT;
    int id;

    nl = nw = nc = id = 0;
    newspace = tabchar = 0;
    printf("+===============================================================+\n");
    printf("|                       WORDS, NEW LINE COUNTER                 |\n");
    printf("+======+==========+==========+============+===========+=========+\n");
    printf("|  ID  | NEW LINE | NEW WORD | CHAR COUNT | NEW SPACE | NEW TAB |\n");
    printf("+===============================================================+\n");

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if(c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        if(c == ' ')
            newspace++;
        if(c == '\t')
            tabchar++;
        else if(state == OUT)
        {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
        id = nl + 1; 
        printf("|  %d  |     %d    |       %d   |       %d      |      %d     |     %d   |\n", id, nl, nw, nc, newspace, tabchar);
    }
}
```

WRONG OUTPUT:

```
+===============================================================+
|                       WORDS, NEW LINE COUNTER                 |
+======+==========+==========+============+===========+=========+
|  ID  | NEW LINE | NEW WORD | CHAR COUNT | NEW SPACE | NEW TAB |
+===============================================================+
I am counting spaces and tab here
|  1  |   0    |      1   |      1   |     0   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      2   |      2   |     1   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      2   |      3   |     1   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      2   |      4   |     1   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      5   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      6   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      7   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      8   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      9   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      10   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      11   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      12   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      3   |      13   |     2   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      14   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      15   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      16   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      17   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      18   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      19   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      4   |      20   |     3   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      5   |      21   |     4   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      5   |      22   |     4   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      5   |      23   |     4   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      5   |      24   |     4   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      6   |      25   |     5   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      6   |      26   |     5   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      6   |      27   |     5   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      6   |      28   |     5   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      7   |      29   |     6   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      7   |      30   |     6   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      7   |      31   |     6   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      7   |      32   |     6   |     0   |
|  1  |   0    |      7   |      33   |     6   |     0   |
|  2  |   1    |      8   |      34   |     6   |     0   |
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
+===============================================================+
|                       WORDS, NEW LINE COUNTER                 |
+======+==========+==========+============+===========+=========+
|  ID  | NEW LINE | NEW WORD | CHAR COUNT | NEW SPACE | NEW TAB |
+===============================================================+
I am counting spaces and tab here
|  2  |   1    |      8   |      34   |     6   |     0   |
```

What am I doing wrong? The output seems almost correct. It seems to me that the potential problem could be that the program does not understand properly the `EOF` in particular the following statement `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` but I am not sure why.

Thanks for pointing in the correct route for the solution.

Comment: Read your code, and step through it line-by-line in your mind, or on paper. Then you will understand why your code is printing many times.

Comment: Hello, yes, the `printf` should be outside as I realized after a while and as the user pointed out. However it still does not work. See here after I moved the `printf` [see here](https://i.imgur.com/FE95Jfx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually working well but you're printing on every iteration.
For your desired output, you should put the `printf` statement after the while block ends.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ++nc;
    if(c == '\n')
        ++nl;
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        state = OUT;
    if(c == ' ')
        newspace++;
    if(c == '\t')
        tabchar++;
    else if(state == OUT)
    {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
    }
    id = nl + 1; 
    printf("|  %d  |     %d    |       %d   |       %d      |      %d     |     %d   |\n", id, nl, nw, nc, newspace, tabchar);
}
```

should be:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ++nc;
    if(c == '\n')
        ++nl;
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        state = OUT;
    if(c == ' ')
        newspace++;
    if(c == '\t')
        tabchar++;
    else if(state == OUT)
    {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
    }
    id = nl + 1; 
    
}

printf("|  %d  |     %d    |       %d   |       %d      |      %d     |     %d   |\n", id, nl, nw, nc, newspace, tabchar);
```

Comment: hello and thanks for reading. I tried it but it is not printing anything ![see here](https://i.imgur.com/FE95Jfx.png). I though that your solution would have worked because I realized it that the `printf` statement should have been outside the cycle. But why is not working?

Comment: It does not seem to properly understand `EOF`? But I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: If you're using an input file it should end. If you're writing on a console, you should use Ctrl + D to send an EOF character.

Comment: gotcha! Thanks it works! Didn't know about Ctrl+D for the EOF!